# How does ufw filter traffic?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I enabled `ufw` firewall with the following command:

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
$
```

Now while I look at the status:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose 
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip 
$
```

It says `deny (incoming)`. But I cannot understand what that means.

Does it mean:

`Deny any packet which is incoming. (i.e. Deny any packet which is incoming regardless of source and destination ip and port address)`

If the above is true, then I am wondering how am i able to browse internet. Because there will be many incoming packets from web-pages I visit. If every incoming packet is denied then I should not be able to surf web-pages. But I am.

If the above was not true then, then does it mean that some specific type of incoming packets that will be denied?If yes, then what kind of packets?

Comment: I think that denies only incoming connections from sources that try to initiate the connection with you (eg when you host a service) rather than incoming connections which are related to outgoing connections that you made (eg web browsing traffic)

Comment: Even I think so.  But what happens with UDP traffic in that case ? In UDP no one tries to initiate a connenction.

Comment: Try check the output `sudo iptables -nvL` to know for sure because in the end that's where your ufw rules end up being inserted into/removed from when you open/close ports in ufw

Answer (score 0):

If my computer is any server then I have to open some specific port(ex. web:80 ssh:22 telnet:23 ftp:21) to listening and anyone who get my link their computer will send me a request to connect and this is incoming meaning.

At the same time, if I am surfing web page my computer will send a request to connect server what ever it is and server will reply me what I request that is "not" incoming. It just a packet of your "outgoing" request then now it get reply.

If I get something wrong. please let me know and Thank you c:

Comment: How does this work for udp ?

Comment: Well, incoming/outgoing for what I say above is work for TCP/UDP.
TCP/UDP is different on first one will check if packet is really success send to server, last one doesn't do that thing it just keep send the packet and ignore is packet really send to server.